# I am running into an error while running my code, which accepts temperatures from user and prints in reverse order, why is that so?

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic, malloc

I was writing this code, given as homework, to satisfy the following:

(Usage of the function realloc isn't permitted)

- initally allocate an array to hold up to 5 temperatures.
- prompt the user to enter temperatures and type the value -100.0 when they are finished.
- if the user fills up the array your program should
  dynamically allocate a new array which is double the size.
- copy the old values across to the new array.
  deallocate the old array.
- continue reading into the new array.

After you finish reading your array your program should, as before, output the temperatures read in reverse (most recent to oldest) with 1 decimal point of precision and a new line at the end of the input

Here is my approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
int size = 5;
float *temperature_first = malloc(sizeof(float)*size);
float *temperature_second;
float inputArray;
int switch_array = 0;
int count = 0;

printf("'Please enter temperature; type '-100' to end: ");
while(inputArray !=-100){

  while((inputArray != -100)&&(count<=size)){
    if(switch_array==0){

      scanf("%f", &temperature_first[count]);
      inputArray = temperature_first[count];
    }

    else{
      scanf("%f", &temperature_second[count]);
      inputArray = temperature_second[count];
    }
    count++;
    }
    if((count>=size)){

      size  = size*2;

      if(switch_array==0){
      temperature_second = malloc(sizeof(float)*size);
      for(int elements = 0;elements<(size/2)+1;elements++){

        temperature_second[elements] = temperature_first[elements];
      }
        free(temperature_first);

        switch_array = 1;
      }
      else{
        temperature_first = malloc(sizeof(float)*size);
        for(int elements = 0;elements<(size/2)+1;elements++){

          temperature_first[elements] = temperature_second[elements];

        }

          free(temperature_second);

          switch_array = 0;
    }
  }
}
for(int i = count-2;i>-1;i--){
  if(i==0){
  if(switch_array==0)
  {
    printf("%0.1f", temperature_first[i]);
   }
   else{
     printf("%0.1f", temperature_second[i]);
   }
  }
  else{
    if(switch_array==0){
      printf("%0.1f ", temperature_first[i]);
    }
    else{
      printf("%0.1f ", temperature_second[i]);
    }
  }
}
printf("\n");

if(switch_array==0){
  free(temperature_first);
}
else{
  free(temperature_second);
}
return 0;
 }
```

while running a specific test:
Input: 16.5 18.8 20.5 21.3 16.2 15.0 17.0 19.7 21.2 56.3 12.5 44.5

Following line is used for compilation:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror=vla -std=c11 -o temperatures02 temperatures02.c
```

This is what I run into:

```
malloc(): corrupted top size
Aborted (core dumped).
```

I'm not too sure why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not tag both C and C++ unless you are using both of them. They are very different languages. Adding pictures is discouraged. Instead you can just copy&paste the text into the question directly.

Comment: As a general rule you should turn up your compiler warnings. For Gcc you can do this using `-Wall -Wextra`. You should get some warning about "using `inputArray` without assigning any value". Also this `if((count>size)||(count==size))` could simply be `if (count>=size)`

Comment: Regarding the task.... Alloc, copy and dealloc... Never heard about `realloc`?

Comment: I think you are making it far more complicated than needed. Don't carry around 2 arrays. Just use one and update that if needed. Only during "alloc+copy+dealloc" you need a second pointer.

Comment: @Gerhardh, thank you very much for your help. Its just that we aren't permitted to use the realloc function (forgot to put it in the conditions, i apologise). I made some changes to my code, however I am still not getting desired output. If you could help me out please?

Comment: My answer also provides the solution without `realloc`. If you insist to keep working with 2 pointers, you will need to run your code in a debugger to check where your execution flow goes and if all the variables contain the values you expect them to contain. There is no reason to keep a second pointer and to do all the stuff to pick the right one, after you deallocated the old array. Just dump that beast.

Answer (score 1):

You simply do not allocate enough memory:

```c
    if((count>size)||(count==size)){

      size  = size*2;

      if(switch_array==0){
      temperature_second = malloc(sizeof(float)*count);
```

You need `size` instead of `count`. Otherwise your entries `count .. size-1` will end up in memory you do not own.

A much shorter version of your code could look like that:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  int size = 5;
  float *temperatures = malloc(sizeof(float)*size); // TODO: Check for NULL
  float temperature;
  int count = 0;

  printf("Please enter temperature; type '-100' to end: ");
  scanf("%f", &temperature);
  // TODO: Check result for error!

  while (temperature != -100) {
    temperatures[count] = temperature;
    count++;

    if (count == size) {
      size *= 2;
#if DO_IT_LIKE_THE_TASK_DEMANDS_IT
      float *newarray = malloc(sizeof(float)*size);
      // TODO: Check for NULL!
      for (int i = 0; i < count-1; i++) {
        newarry[i] = temperatures[i];
      }
      free(temperatures);
#else
      float *newarray = realloc(temperatures, sizeof(float)*size);
      // TODO: Check for NULL!
#endif
      temperatures = newarray; 
    }

    printf("Please enter temperature; type '-100' to end: ");
    scanf("%f", &temperature);
    // TODO: Check result for error!
  }

  // Print them backwards (not in the task but in your code
  // Last element was put into temperatures[count] before we did count++.
  // Therefore now we need to start at index count-1, not count-2

  for(int i = count-1;i>-1;i--) {
    if (i==0) {
      printf("%0.1f", temperatures[i]);
    }
    else {
      printf("%0.1f ", temperatures[i]);
    }
  }
  printf("\n");

  free(temperatures);
  return 0;
 }
```

Tested at https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler shows:

```
Please enter temperature; type '-100' to end: 16.5
Please enter temperature; type '-100' to end: 18.8
Please enter temperature; type '-100' to end: 20.5
Please enter temperature; type '-100' to end: 21.3
Please enter temperature; type '-100' to end: 16.2
Please enter temperature; type '-100' to end: 15.0
Please enter temperature; type '-100' to end: 17.0
Please enter temperature; type '-100' to end: 19.7
Please enter temperature; type '-100' to end: 21.2
Please enter temperature; type '-100' to end: 56.3
Please enter temperature; type '-100' to end: 44.5
Please enter temperature; type '-100' to end: -100
44.5 56.3 21.2 19.7 17.0 15.0 16.2 21.3 20.5 18.8 16.5


...Program finished with exit code 0
```